# Change styling of a psuedo after element with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change the styling of a psuedo `:after` element with javascript something like this:

```
document.querySelector('#test:after').attr("style", "content:url('blabla.png')");
```

Is there any workaround to change the image after 1 click like this:

```
var timesClicked = 0;
span = document.querySelector('.socialShare');

span.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  timesClicked++;
  if (timesClicked > 1) {
      document.querySelector('#socialShare').style.left = '-60px';
      timesClicked = 0;
      console.log(timesClicked)
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#socialShare').style.left = '0';
    document.querySelector('#socialShare:after').attr("style", "content:url('blabla.png')");
    console.log(timesClicked)
  }
});
```

Or maybe better transform the image it is  about an arrow which needs to point the other way when div is expanded

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: @dfsq do you have any work around because I want to change the image url when click twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change styles of pseudo elements with javascript, because they are not part of the DOM, and so do not have any API to work with.

Usual approach is to change classes of the element itself and have those classes affect related pseudo elements. For example in your case:

```
// Add class selected to element
document.querySelector('#test').classList.add('selected')
```

In CSS:

```css
#test.selected::after {
  content: url('blabla.png');
}
```